# How do you commit to a GitHub repo using a Cloudflare worker?

Tags: javascript, git, github, cloudflare-workers

I have a Cloudflare worker that I would like to use to commit to a GitHub repository automatically. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: hi, we noticed that you reposted after having deleted this https://stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard?flagtype=postother please avoid doing that and edit the original question instead thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [Wrangler](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-cloudflare-workers-with-wrangler) which is made by **Cloudflare** to deploy your code through the **Github Actions**.

On [Github](https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler) there is the repository which explains how to do a first setup and to manage your worker.

Comment: How do I use this to make a Cloudflare worker commit to a GitHub repo?

Comment: The commits get pushed to your Github repo first, from there wrangler will build and deploy your application as mentioned here https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-cloudflare-workers-with-wrangler#use-cases in other words, you don't really commit first to your wrangler and then to Github, because the latter is hosting your code and wrangler simply deploys and builds the application